# curl always respond with 401 Unauthorized but only with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, icloud, caldav

I have a class that retreiving data from remote server (user/calendar data from icloud) using curl. Everything works perfectly, when i'm using single file, but if i use this class in Laravel (ver. 5.4) i'm receiving `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` every time.
Here is short version of class code:

```
<?php
class CalDavClient
{
    protected $url;
    protected $server;
    protected $user;
    protected $user_id;
    protected $calendar_id;
    protected $password;
    protected $depth = 1;
    protected $user_agent = "DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)";

    public function __construct($server, $user, $password, $user_id = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->server = $server;
        if(isset($user_id))
            $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function setDepth($depth = null)
    {
        if (isset($depth))
            $this->depth = $depth;
        return $this->depth;
    }

    public function getUserId()
    {
        $principal_request = '<d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:"><d:prop><d:current-user-principal /></d:prop></d:propfind>';
        $url = $this->server;
        $res = $this->doRequest($url, $principal_request);
        $response=simplexml_load_string($res);
        //Principal URL
        $principal_url=$response->response[0]->propstat[0]->prop[0]->{'current-user-principal'}->href;
        $userID = explode("/", $principal_url);
        return $this->user_id = $userID[1];
    }

    private function doRequest($url, $xml)
    {
        //Init cURL
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($c, [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            //Set headers
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$this->user:$this->password"),
                "Depth: " . $this->depth,
                "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml),
                "User-Agent: DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)",
                'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
            ),
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
            //Set SSL
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            //Set request and XML
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PROPFIND",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        ]);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //Execute
        $error = curl_error($c);
        $response = curl_exec($c);
        $info = curl_getinfo($c);
        //Close cURL
        curl_close($c);
        dd($error, $response, $info);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And this is how it works in my controller:

```
public function test(Request $request) {
        $client = new CalDavClient('https://p01-caldav.icloud.com', $request->user, $request->pass);
        $client->getUserId();
    }
```

I've tried different variations of curl settings (ssl on/off, auth in options/in headers and so on...), but result still the same. Also trying Guzzle, but still same thing.
But what is weird for me is when i'm using exact same code, but just including it into regular php file everything working fine.